# How to obtain the random seed from TensorFlow?

Tags: python, numpy, random, tensorflow

I want to be able to reproduce training sessions of Neural Networks in TensorFlow. When I run TensorFlow I assume it has some rand state that makes it choose some specific initialization for the variables. This is what I think I am mostly interested in reproducing. I think I can successfully reproduce the SGD steps because I am able to obtain the numpy seed that makes me have random choices of batches (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20911147/choose-random-seed-and-save-it/38165503#38165503)). Since the nature of numpy is to have a weird tuples for keeping random seends, re-using that state to make a seed in TensorFlow is unclear to me. Is it possible to get the TensorFlow random seed?

---

I did read some of [the documentation of TensorFlow on random seeds](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.9/api_docs/python/constant_op.html#set_random_seed) and it seems that it mainly says how to set seeds rather than read them. Does this mean that the best way to get a random seed from TensorFlow is by asking the computers OS to get a random number? Or maybe to ask [python for a random seed](https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html) when it runs? Or maybe a combination of those plus the current time or something like that?

Maybe something like:

```
random.seed()
random_seed = random.getstate()
tf_set_random_seed(random_seed)
```

---

I've decided to do:

```
rand = int(os.urandom(64).encode('hex'), 16)
results['tf_rand_seed'] = rand
tf.set_random_seed(rand)
```

is that a good idea?

Comment: Why don't set a seed yourself and store it?

Comment: @martijnn2008 that is sort of what my second suggestion is. Though, I'd like to make sure I generate a good random seed, even if python helps me to get it. I'd also be interested to see if tensorflow allows something similar to this directly if possible.

Comment: Read the [source code](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/framework/random_seed.py).

Comment: @Aya I think I might use: `rand = int(os.urandom(64).encode('hex'), 16)` for the moment since it seems urandom is a good source of randomness.

Comment: 64 bytes of randomness seems like rather a lot. Looking at the source, it's truncated to 32 bits anyway, so `os.urandom(4)` ought to suffice.

Comment: Numpy as the ability to acquire the random state `np.random.get_state()` and later set it. I wonder why tensorflow does not expose this.